# how to install rosserial for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ubuntu 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208353/how-to-install-rosserial-for-ubuntu-14.04/) by [laconic_Knight](https://answers.ros.org/users/22328/laconic_knight/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Kindly follow this link. Might help you out.

http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup

---

Originally posted by [vamsy](https://answers.ros.org/users/34300/vamsy/) with karma: 16 on 2018-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0